# Calculate the duration between now and next local time

Tags: nodatime

I need to determine the duration between now and the next occurrance of a local time. Here's what I've got:

```cs
Duration GetDuration(IClock clock, LocalTime time, DateTimeZone zone)
{
    // get the current time in this zone
    var now = clock.Now.InZone(zone);

    // find the time in our zone today
    var timeToday = zone.AtLeniently(now.Date + time);

    // find the time in our zone tomorrow
    var timeTomorrow = zone.AtLeniently(now.Date.PlusDays(1) + time);

    // get the next occurrance of that time
    var next = new[]{timeToday, timeTomorrow}.Where(x => x > now).Min();        

    // calculate the duration between now and the next occurance of that time
    var duration = next.ToInstant() - now.ToInstant();  
    Debug.Assert(duration > Duration.Zero);
    return duration;
}
```

And a test to get the duration between now and the next instant of 5PM eastern time:

```cs
var duration = GetDuration(
    SystemClock.Instance,
    new LocalTime(17,00),
    DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["US/Eastern"]);
```

My question is, since I'm new to NodaTime, am I taking any unnecessary steps or missing any shortcuts?

Answer (score 3):

This code is a bit more long-winded than it needs to be - I'd do most of the work in the "local" context, and only convert back to the time zone when you know the `LocalDateTime` you want to map.

```cs
var now = clock.Now.InZone(zone);
// Change this to <= time if you want it to be a "strictly next".
var nextDate = now.TimeOfDay < time ? now.Date : now.Date.PlusDays(1);

return zone.AtLeniently(nextDate + time).ToInstant() - now.ToInstant();
```

`AtLeniently` will always return a value which is no *earlier* than the given `LocalDateTime` (it returns the later of two ambiguous options, and the start of the interval after a skipped time), so you don't need to worry about DST transitions.

As an aside, feedback about whether the `ToInstant()` calls in the last line are annoying would be useful. I'd at least *consider* adding a `Duration operator-(ZonedDateTime, ZonedDateTime)` to 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the kind of advice I was looking for. My feedback about the minus operator between instances of ZonedDateTime: Yes, its absence is annoying. It would be a nice improvement. I was going to bring that up, but you've done it for me. It would probably make since to do the same for OffsetDateTime.

Comment: @RonnieOverby: Yup. Raised https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=323

Comment: If you want to make it really convenient, I'd say add the operator between any types that can be directly converted to Instant. Although, I have the sense that you favor explicitness over convenience. This type of thing would soften the barrier to entry.

Comment: @RonnieOverby: I'm in favour of being explicit about some things, but not necessarily everything. I'm not sure I'd want something like `-(ZonedDateTime, OffsetDateTime)` for example... but pairs of operands of the *same* type which can be converted to `Instant` makes sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet - If we ever get around to doing a "Noda Time Cookbook" - this would be a great addition. :)

Comment: @Matt: Good plan. Will add it to the recipes page when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is like this:

```
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate now2 = now.plusDays(4);
    ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(now, now2);
```